# To fetch Vm details with Publisher details

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to fetch Publisher,offer,plan and id for all virtual machines in all subscriptions.

Can anyone suggest any custom powershell script for same or any other way for same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
az vm list --query '[].{id: id, name: name, plan: plan, publisher: storageProfile.imageReference.publisher, offer: storageProfile.imageReference.offer}' -o json
```